# fetching the best locations

Tags: java, algorithm, mongodb, coordinates, latitude-longitude

what's the best approach ( or an existing algorithm, library ) to get the best items among a large set of location data ( latitude , longitude ); say there's +1M location hits, and the goal is to get the best 100 items which generally describe the whole path (per user query)

I was thinking of precalculation for the "best items" set (based on predefined time-sections), whenever a new entry comes; but I'm not sure about it

P.S : I'm using java for the programming language , & mongodb for the backend storage

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about the 100 nearest locations? If so, you have described the n-Nearest-Neighbours problem.

The best thing to do is to build a [kd-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree), and then perform a search as described by the wikipedia article.

There are many implementations of this, for example in python in `scikit-learn`

If you mean something else by 'best', I'm afraid you'll need to elaborate further.

Comment: suppose we have 1M location info. (in the form of latitude,longitudes ) between point A and point B. the goal is to fetch the maximum of 100 items between these 1M record, which can describe the whole path between position:A to position:B (in the best way)